# What is an efficient way to import and use local javascript file in a vue js component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have written in script tag of Vue.js component as follows:

```js
require("./js/swiper.min.js");
require("./js/wow.min.js");
export default {
    mounted(){
         var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{pagination: '.swiper- 
         pagination', paginationClickable: true,});
         new WOW().init();
    } 
}
```

which results me the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only
property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'"
```

It is working proper in `index.html` (a simple HTML file), but in Vue.js component it gives error.

Is it right way to use local javascript file in Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a conflict between how exports works with `require` vs `import`

you can use `require` with `module.exports` and `import` with `export defaults`. Right now you're mixing them, which could lead to a problem.

This is explained well in here: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2934#issuecomment-292698456

> You should not do things like:

```
// myModule.js
import x from 'module-x'
...
module.exports = something
```

> instead:
>
> common.js way

```
// myModule.js
const x = require('module-x')
// Here there is a trick, if module-x is exported as ES6 with a default export it would be
const x = require('module-x').default
...
module.exports = something
```

> or
>
> ES6 way

```
// myModule.js
import x from 'module-x'
...
export default something
```

Comment: What you answered is right. But, the real problem is with .Vue, you can't import modules into a vue component. You have to install into Vue prototype inorder to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case its right to include in index.html. But if you want to include your local modules or any js modules (not libraries), you can refer to [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-helper-functions-for-imported-modules-in-vuejs-vue-template/6266)